# Existe alguma relação entre as vogais em Português e as vogais Māori

Tags: vogais

Recentemente estava assistindo [um vídeo no YouTube a respeito da cultura Māori](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pPthzQrFy8), povo originário da Nova Zelândia.

Durante o vídeo o autor explica para o Povo Australiano, especialmente, que as vogais em Māori são pronunciadas exatamente igual ao Português.

E aí a dificuldade das pessoas que não falam Português pronunciarem corretamente as palavras em Māori.

Aí minha questão: as duas línguas compartilham alguma coisa mais do que a similaridade fonética?

Answer (score 2):

O maori tem 5 vogais, o português tem mais (a falar só das orais tónicas, há 8 ou 9). A distribução delas no maori é uma que se vê muito nas línguas incluindo, por exemplo, o castelhano ou japonês.

Segundo o WALS, as línguas com cinco vogais formam um terço de todas as línguas no mundo.

Aliás, é normal que nestas línguas as vogais sejam /a/, /e/, /i/, /o/, /u/ porque isto permite uma clara e óptima distinção entre elas (se tivessem /a/, /ɐ/, /ä/, /æ/, e /ɛ/, seria mesmo muito difícil ouvilas claramente).

Portanto, apesar de qualquer semelhança percebida, não há conexão.